# NSPredicate search in NSArray containing NSArrays with custom objects

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, iteration, nspredicate

I have an `NSArray` called `groups` containing `NSArray` objects which each contain `QuestionSub` objects, which in its turn inherit from the `Question` class.

The Question class consist of, amongst others, an `NSString` value called `Id`. This is the string I would like to search for.
The problem is that `QuestionSub` contains an `NSString` called `parent`, which is a reference  to a parent Question; hence I cannot use an `NSPredicate` with query the `ANY` statement since it will match on any equal string.

My problem is that my search doesn't return a result. However, I can't seem to find the right query for my `NSPredicate` to get a correct result.

This is my code:

```
/**
 *  Get the (QuestionSub)[QuestionSub] for a questuon GUID
 *
 *  @param guid NSString The GUID of the question
 *
 *  @return QuestionSub The QuestionSub
 */
- (QuestionSub *)getQuestionForGuid:(NSString *)guid
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Id == %@", guid];
    NSArray *filtered = [self.groups filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    if (filtered.count > 0)
    {
        return [filtered objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

This is a representation of my `NSArray`:
[image: The representation]

Comment: See the image added above, there is sample data. Contents of the array is auto-populated from JSON, so I don't really have an example unfortunately... other then the above of course.

Comment: again, there is no such code. The contents of the array is auto-populated from a JSON stucture. Sure, you could close-vote the question with regards to that it **lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem**, but that would be untrue. There is sufficient information and its a well documented question. Besides; two answers, so far, would indicate that.

Comment: I don't think we should turn this into a long discussion, I just thought it would be useful with some sample data. An array with some arrays with a few dictionaries with the relevant keys. You can do a lot with subqueries, but without any sample data it is hard to work on - unless you want the answerers to also construct your test data set for you. BTW, did you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ? What I am asking for is a compilable example so we all know what we are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Given that the array is shown in the picture above, the example code of the actual problem is included, the question is not specific to *my* `NSArray` and the explanation exists; I feel that I have accomplished those goals. Yes, I have read the MCVE (and other rules) and, with regards to the image above, it complies to the **Verifiable** category. However, I do thank you for your concern and for your effort to improve the post-quality on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that *filteredArrayUsingPredicate:* filters the entire groups array. So ANY operator says to filter out all subarrays which contain Question object with needed Id property.

In your Example you have Questions with the same *Id* and *parent* in the same subarray, so ANY works here properly and there is no difference between == and CONTAINS for our goal.

To get needed result you first need to flatten your groups to one-dimensional array of Questions and then apply your predicate.

Unfortunately NSArray class does't provide any method to flatten multi-dimensional array (:

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid of that. I solved it now with a `for` loop which apply the `NSPredicate` on each sub `NSArray` in the `groups` array. Its a bit risky to do that, but given that the array would not contain more than tops 5-10 groups I'll take the risk. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you can use string comparison predicates, can you try this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Id CONTAINS[c] %@", guid];
```

Comment: Does the same thing as `ANY`, doesn't respect `Id` so it matches on both the `_parent` and `_Id` which means that the `filtered` (predicate result) has multiple results/rows.